# Eratosthenes' and Sundaram's prime sieves in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I recently started playing with Python. What can I do better?

```
def sieve_of_sundaram(limit):
    new_limit = (limit - 1) // 2
    boolean_list = [True] * new_limit;
    i = 1
    j = i
    while (i + j + 2 * i * j <= new_limit):
        while (i + j + 2 * i * j <= new_limit):
            boolean_list[2 * i * j + i + j - 1] = False
            j += 1
        i += 1
        j = i
    primes = [2]
    for i in range(0, new_limit):
        if boolean_list[i]:
            primes.append(i * 2 + 3)
    return primes

def sieve_of_eratosthenes(limit):
    boolean_list = [True] * limit;
    for i in range(2, limit):
        if i * i > limit:
            break
        while boolean_list[i - 1] == False:
            i += 1
        for j in range(i * i, limit + 1, i):
            boolean_list[j - 1] = False
    primes = []
    for i in range(1, limit):
        if boolean_list[i] == True:
            primes.append(i + 1)
    return primes


i = 100
sundaram_primes = sieve_of_sundaram(i)
eratosthenes_primes = sieve_of_eratosthenes(i)

print("Sundaram primes count: ", len(sundaram_primes))
print(sundaram_primes)
print("Eratosthenes primes count: ", len(eratosthenes_primes))
print(eratosthenes_primes)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. FYI, there is no reason to add irrelevant filler text like "lorem ipsum", just explain what the code does and leave it at that. In this case it's pretty self-explaining so very little is needed.

Comment: @Phrancis I couldn't post it because "most of the post is code".

Comment: Understood. I removed the extra text and moved the text to the top and had no problems. Anyways, I hope you get great answers!

Answer (score 5):

There are some curious inconsistencies between the Eratosthenes and Sundaram code.

> ```
>     for i in range(2, limit):
>         if i * i > limit:
>             break
> ```

is IMO more Pythonic than

> ```
>     i = 1
>     j = i
>     while (i + j + 2 * i * j <= new_limit):
>         ...
>         i += 1
>         j = i
> ```

We can refactor the second into something similar to the first: firstly, observe that there's no need to repeat the assignment `j = i`:

```
    i = 1
    while (i + i + 2 * i * i <= new_limit):
        j = i
        ...
        i += 1
```

Then simplify algebraically:

```
    i = 1
    while (2 * i * (i + 1) <= new_limit):
        j = i
        ...
        i += 1
```

And finally replace with `range`:

```
    for i in range(1, new_limit + 1):
        if 2 * i * (i + 1) > new_limit:
            break
        j = i
        ...
```

As noted by Janne, you can then refactor the inner loop to also use `range`...

---

The indexing of the arrays in both is a bit tricky. Are the maintenance costs worth saving four bytes of memory? If so, would it at least be worth leaving a comment to explain why (for example) the primes recovered by the Sundaram sieve are `2 * i + 3` instead of the `2 * i + 1` which someone who just read the Wikipedia page would expect?

---

> ```
>     primes = [2]
>     for i in range(0, new_limit):
>         if boolean_list[i]:
>             primes.append(i * 2 + 3)
> ```

can be written as a one-liner using something called *list comprehensions*. This is something that's worth learning because it's very common style for Python.

```
    primes = [2] + [i * 2 + 3 for i in range(0, new_limit) if boolean_list[i]]
```

---

> ```
>         if boolean_list[i]:
> ```

...

> ```
>         if boolean_list[i] == True:
> ```

What's the difference?

Answer: the first one is better style. `x == True` should be rewritten as `x` ; and `y == False` or `y != True` should be rewritten as `not y`. With good variable names this usually gives a very natural reading.

---

On the subject of names: `boolean_list` tells me the type, but what I care about is the meaning. For Eratosthenes that's easy: a `True` means that the index is a prime, and a `False` means that it's a composite number, so `is_prime` is a good name. For Sundaram the exact interpretation is a bit trickier, but `is_prime` would still work.

Comment: `for i in range(2, limit):` followed by `if i * i > limit:` is horrible IMHO. Why not just calculate the correct limit directly?

Answer (score 4):

- `sieve_of_eratosthenes` has an inner `while` loop that increments `i`. This is not useful because it will not advance the outer `for` loop, and you end up looping over the same values multiple times.
- `sieve_of_sundaram` repeats the expression `i + j + 2 * i * j`. You could instead use `for` loops with an appropriate step size.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the feedback, i found it very useful. Actually I managed to improve the running time of of both algorithms by a lot. Particularly proud of Sundaram's sieve. Check it out

Answer (score 2):

## Theory

```
def sieve_of_eratosthenes(limit):
    boolean_list = [True] * limit;
```

- There's no need for `;`.
- It might be easier to add one element to the list and use 1-based indexing.

---

```
    for i in range(2, limit):
        if i * i > limit:
            break
```

- There's no need for this check. It will be integrated into your `range` later. If `i * i` is larger than `limit`, `range(i * i, limit + 1, i)` is empty and nothing happens.

---

```
        while boolean_list[i - 1] == False:
            i += 1
```

- You also don't need this loop, you already have `for i` above.

---

```
        for j in range(i * i, limit + 1, i):
            boolean_list[j - 1] = False
```

- This looks fine. With 1-based indexing, it becomes `boolean_list[j] = False`

---

```
    primes = []
    for i in range(1, limit):
        if boolean_list[i] == True:
            primes.append(i + 1)
```

- You already iterated over the whole range earlier. You could append the primes directly in the above loop.

## Code

Here's the refactored code. It's much shorter and 3 times faster than your original code for the primes below 1 million:

```
def sieve_of_eratosthenes(limit):
    is_prime = [True] * (limit + 1)
    primes = []
    for i in range(2, limit + 1):
        if is_prime[i]:
            primes.append(i)
            for j in range(i * i, limit + 1, i):
                is_prime[j] = False
    return primes
```

It's even shorter if you return a generator:

```
def sieve_of_eratosthenes(limit):
    is_prime = [True] * (limit + 1)
    for i in range(2, limit + 1):
        if is_prime[i]:
            yield i
            for j in range(i * i, limit + 1, i):
                is_prime[j] = False
```

Comment: It's worth noting that if you use `numpy` for this, you use a fraction of the memory, and get rid of some of the loops. The two things that change are `isprime = np.ones(k,dtype=np.bool)` and `isprime[np.arange(i * i, limit + 1, i)]=False`. The result will be significantly faster.

Comment: @OscarSmith: Interesting. I might be missing something, but this [code](https://pastebin.com/cwWftB9m) was actually slower than the pure python implementation (not taking `import` into account, obviously).

Comment: how high are you testing? at `limit=10**7`, it is about 2x as fast for me.

Comment: @EricDuminil I have implemented sieve of Sundaram for LeetCode Count Primes problem. My pure Python 3 solution is ~ 130ms. What is your best timing?

Comment: @JulStrat: I didn't look at Sundaram yet. Will try to do so this evening.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you some performance improvements.

1. Sieve of Sundaram can be implemented using only addition.
2. Rewrite inner `for` loop as slice assignment.
3. Use `list` `comprehension` in last step.
4. For sieve you can use list of integers or bytearray.